# Avalonia: How to display PNG as image?

Tags: f#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I haven't seen an F# example of accomplishing this, or any examples similar enough to what I am trying to do, so hopefully a solution here will be helpful to others.

I am using Avalonia with F# to build a simple UI. I want to include images in my UI, but have spent hours looking at documentation and examples and everything I've seen looks to be overcomplicated (maybe it really is just that complicated?).

I am creating an image like:

```
let b = (Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap @"C:\Images\icon.png")
Image.create [
    Image.source b
]
```

This just displays nothing. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I created a test app like this: `dotnet new funcui.basic -n AvaloniaTest`. Then I added your code in `Counter.fs` and the PNG file is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

To add more detail to my comment above, here's what works for me:

```ml
let view =
    Component(fun ctx ->
        let b = new Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap("Small.png")
        Image.create [
            Image.source b
        ]
    )
```

Result is:

[image]